# In-App Store Product View, not working on IOS 5, how to test?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, methods

I'm using the new API for an In-App appstore product view. I'm aware it should only work on IOS 6 and later, however, my app is targeted for ios 5 and later. Now, when you tab on the button that takes you to store, the app will go lemon and freeze on you!

`SKStoreProductViewController`

How would I test if this device is able to perform this function? or if this is ios 6 and later?

I'm looking for something similar to "In-app mail" which it has a method called `CanSendMail`, is there such a method for `SKStore`?

**In Addition**

I have the framework weakly linked as an `Option`.

**UPADTE**

I tried to use this but still not working!! and nothing logs :(

```
if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error %@ with User Info %@.", error, [error userInfo]);


    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                    message:@"Your device doesn't support In-App Product View"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];


    } else {
        // Present Store Product View Controller
        [self presentViewController:storeProductViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}];

}
```

Comment: You have a look at the [SDK Compatibility Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000163i) for full details on properly performing runtime checks such as this.

Comment: @rmaddy so I understand there isn't a special method for this class such as `CanSendMail` in `MailComposer`?

Comment: No, there isn't. I never implied that there was. And even if there was, it would be useless under iOS 5.x since the class wasn't added until 6.0. The link I provided will help you properly use classes, methods, and frameworks that don't exist across every version of iOS that your app supports. See Adam's answer for the proper check for the `SKStoreProductViewController` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this works best:

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(v)                  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedSame)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(v)              ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)                 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)     ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedDescending)

if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"6.0")) {

// iOS Version 5.1 and older    

}

if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.0")) {

// iOS Version 6.0 and later    

}
```

copy your Store Product View code into later than 6.0 and your fallback code into 5.1 and older.

I learnt this from here. Good Luck!!

Answer (score 2):

The general way of testing if a class is available at runtime is to use [`NSClassFromString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/reference/reference.html).  So, you could do something like this:

```
Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"SKStoreProductViewController");
if (cls)
{
    // The device is iOS 6.0 or higher, so it's safe to use this class
    SKStoreProductViewController *viewController = [[cls alloc] init];
    ...
}
else
{
    // The device is pre-iOS 6.0; show an error message or have some other
    // reasonable fallback behavior
}
```

If the framework you're using is not available in the minimum version of iOS that you're targeting, then you must also make sure that you **weak link** the framework.  As @rmaddy pointed out, you should see the [SDK Compatibility GUide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000163i) for the full, gory details.

Comment: In the past you would still get a crash due to the reference to the class name in the call to `alloc`. Is this still an issue? I always call `alloc` on the `Class` object obtained from `NSClassFromString`.

Comment: @rmaddy: I think you're right, I was a little fuzzy on the details and reconstructed my example from memory.

Comment: Under which method should I put this?

Comment: @AdamRosenfield, It's ture! I got a crash when I had it in the same method were I had setup my store product view!